# How to update List<String> entity in room database?

Tags: android

I have an entity in my app which contains a column of List. I can store and view with no issues but when i try to update i get an error.

I tried using ArrayList. That didn't work either.

This is what is the function in my DAO.

```
@Query("UPDATE Circles SET members = :list WHERE ID LIKE :search")
public void updateMembers(List<String> list, String search);
```

This is the columninfo:

```
@ColumnInfo
private List<String> members;
```

I was expecting that it would update the current list. However it is giving ab error:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "?": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE Circles SET members = ?,? WHERE ID LIKE ?
```